# How to expose Proxy SOAP webservice in Mule with JMS queue

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a requirement of hosting a SOAP web service and hosting a Proxy web service to that main web service...
So I have the following :-

1. A SOAP web service exposed to perform a CRUD operation.
2. A Proxy web service to that main web service

Now I have created the SOAP web service which is exposed and perform CRUD operation and it's working fine .. Now the issue is with Proxy web service .. Following is my Proxy web service config :-

```
<flow name="ProxyFlow" doc:name="ProxyFlow">
 <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8086" path="proxy/mainData" doc:name="HTTP" />
<cxf:proxy-service port="MainDataPort" namespace="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1"  service="MainDataService"  payload="body" wsdlLocation="MainData.wsdl" doc:name="SOAP"/>
<mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/> 
<jms:outbound-endpoint queue="ProxyQueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
</flow>

<flow name="ClientProxy" doc:name="ClientProxy">
<jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="Active_MQ" address="jms://tcp:ProxyQueue" doc:name="JMS" exchange-pattern="request-response" disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true" responseTimeout="90000"/>
<byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>  
<cxf:proxy-client payload="body" doc:name="SOAP" />
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"   host="localhost" port="8082" path="mainData" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" />
</flow>
```

Now as you can see the the proxy web service is using JMS queue .. When I trigger the Proxy web service from SOAPUI ..I get the following exception :-

```
INFO  2014-09-11 21:16:46,475 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.jms.transformers.ObjectToJMSMessage
ERROR 2014-09-11 21:16:46,483 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Source was not of a supported type. Valid types are Message, String, Map, InputStream, List, byte[], Serializable or OutputHandler, but was DepthXMLStreamReader (javax.jms.JMSException)
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Source was not of a supported type. Valid types are Message, String, Map, InputStream, List, byte[], Serializable or OutputHandler, but was DepthXMLStreamReader(JMS Code: null) (javax.jms.JMSException)
  org.mule.transport.jms.JmsMessageUtils:144 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/jms/JMSException.html)
2. Source was not of a supported type. Valid types are Message, String, Map, InputStream, List, byte[], Serializable or OutputHandler, but was DepthXMLStreamReader (javax.jms.JMSException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.transport.jms.transformers.AbstractJmsTransformer:79 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
javax.jms.JMSException: Source was not of a supported type. Valid types are Message, String, Map, InputStream, List, byte[], Serializable or OutputHandler, but was DepthXMLStreamReader
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsMessageUtils.toMessage(JmsMessageUtils.java:144)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.transformers.AbstractJmsTransformer.transformToMessage(AbstractJmsTransformer.java:66)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.transformers.ObjectToJMSMessage.transformMessage(ObjectToJMSMessage.java:54)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

ERROR 2014-09-11 21:16:47,522 [ActiveMQ Session Task-2] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : "Message with id "ID:ANIRBAN-PC-49972-1410450386406-1:1:14:1:1" has been redelivered 1 times on endpoint "jms://tcp:ProxyQueue", which exceeds the maxRedelivery setting of 0 on the connector "Active_MQ". Message payload is of type: ActiveMQTextMessage
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. "Message with id "ID:ANIRBAN-PC-49972-1410450386406-1:1:14:1:1" has been redelivered 1 times on endpoint "jms://tcp:ProxyQueue", which exceeds the maxRedelivery setting of 0 on the connector "Active_MQ". Message payload is of type: ActiveMQTextMessage (org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.MessageRedeliveredException)
  org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.JmsXRedeliveryHandler:81 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/transport/jms/redelivery/MessageRedeliveredException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.MessageRedeliveredException: "Message with id "ID:ANIRBAN-PC-49972-1410450386406-1:1:14:1:1" has been redelivered 1 times on endpoint "jms://tcp:ProxyQueue", which exceeds the maxRedelivery setting of 0 on the connector "Active_MQ". Message payload is of type: ActiveMQTextMessage
    at org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.JmsXRedeliveryHandler.handleRedelivery(JmsXRedeliveryHandler.java:81)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.MultiConsumerJmsMessageReceiver$JmsWorker.preProcessMessage(MultiConsumerJmsMessageReceiver.java:512)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractReceiverWorker$1$1.process(AbstractReceiverWorker.java:117)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

WARN  2014-09-11 21:16:56,369 [[Dummysimpleclientwebservice].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://services.vertu.com/schema/MainData/V1}MainDataService has thrown exception, unwinding now
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.databinding.stax.StaxDataBinding$XMLStreamDataWriter.write(StaxDataBinding.java:147)
    at org.apache.cxf.databinding.stax.StaxDataBinding$XMLStreamDataWriter.write(StaxDataBinding.java:135)
    at org.apache.cxf.databinding.stax.StaxDataBinding$XMLStreamDataWriter.write(StaxDataBinding.java:131)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.resume(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:232)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor$1.write(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:426)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.writeResponse(HttpServerConnection.java:353)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageProcessTemplate.sendResponseToClient(HttpMessageProcessTemplate.java:137)
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase.sendResponseIfNeccessary(FlowProcessingPhase.java:153)
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase.access$000(FlowProcessingPhase.java:29)
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase$1$1.process(FlowProcessingPhase.java:78)
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase$1$1.process(FlowProcessingPhase.java:63)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:109)
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase$1.run(FlowProcessingPhase.java:62)
    at org.mule.transport.TrackingWorkManager$TrackeableWork.run(TrackingWorkManager.java:267)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Now I can find that the main webservice is called internally and the Data are created in DB.. But I guess it's unable to transform the response back to the Proxy client .. any suggestion ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the proxy client in the following way.

```
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"   host="localhost" port="8082" path="mainData" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" >
   <cxf:proxy-client payload="body" doc:name="SOAP" />        
</http:outbound-endpoint>
<logger level="INFO" message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" />
```

The HTTP outbound is retruning the response in the format of DepthXMLStreamReader. The above format of Proxy-client should help. The logger will read the response from the StreamReader so it is in a serializable format.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Even after adding the Logger?  Did you try adding Object to String or  ByteArray to String transformer?

Comment: Yes .. Now it worked after adding the logger .. what's the reason behind it ?? .. Could you pls tell me the exact reason why it is expecting a String format at the response side ???

Comment: The response from the HTTP outbound is a stream. When another operation is performed on the payload(which is in the form of stream). The stream is read completely and is available as a proper object. In the previous case when you were posting the response from HTTP to JMS the response is still  a stream which JMS is anot able to take.

Comment: Please upvote the answers if they were useful to you. This encourages the users to provide more help.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the payload after the Http outbound is stream so, it need to be converted into String or else will be getting the exception.

So, the solution that worked me is :-

```
<logger level="INFO" message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" />
```

Alternately I realized that putting a `<byte-array-to-string-transformer>` will also work